# How to setup project structure for EF and repository pattern

Tags: c#, asp.net, design-patterns, entity-framework-6, repository-pattern

I'm working my way through a tutorial for EF 6 and the repository pattern. The entire project is broken into folders but I'm attempting to understand how I could separate this into separate layers/class library projects.

I currently have the below (Using DB first approach)

- `.EDMX` file, connected to my database (for this example I will use 2 tables `Customers` and `Addresses`)
- Partial classes (overriding `Customers` and `Addresses`)
- `IRepository`

  ```
    public interface IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class`
  ```

  This interface is then used to create other repositories i.e.

  ```
    ICustomer (public interface ICustomer : IRepository<Customer>
  ```

I then have `IUnitOfWork`, and finally a web application (webforms).

So my approach is to add a class library (I will call this `DAL`), add EF 6 and my `.EDMX` context file along with a folder for all entities needing a partial class for.

How should the remaining areas be separated into class libraries? Should I have `IRepository` in a separate class (maybe called `Services`)? If yes would I just add the `Customer`/`Addresses` interfaces into this library along with classes that would have pull the data i.e. Add, Get Delete?

For unit of work - should this also reside in another class library?

WebApp - as per the course I would add a reference to unit of Work class library (as far as I understand).

Would be great if someone can show me an example to fill in this missing gap as i have seen some online threads but cant find a way to connect everything?

Answer (score 0):

To keep it short, `Repository` and `Unit of work` are essentially part of your Data structure. In your case, your `DAL` project.

`Repositories` will be how you will abstract your data layer, how you access your `DbSets`.

`Unit of work` is how you access your repositories and keep track of changes.

If you have a `Core` class library or something, that is where your interfaces (`IRepository`, `IUnitOfWork`, ...) should be placed.

This [article here](https://medium.com/swlh/building-a-nice-multi-layer-net-core-3-api-c68a9ef16368) shows how to structure with a .NET Core API and Entity Framework Core, but the idea should be the same for .NET framework and EF6.